# Christodoulou's paper on naked singularities in inhomogeneous dust collapse

Tags: differential-equations, dg.differential-geometry, reference-request, general-relativity

I have been studying of late about formation of naked singularities in certain collapse scenarios in Einstein's theory. It seems to me that the canonical paper to read about how such a formation is established is the 1984 paper by Christodoulou in Communications in Mathematical Physics. ( http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=742192 )

I was wondering if there is a reference which gives a more modern rewriting of the proof in that paper which say sort of highlights the generic technique of the proof which the reader can take away from there for other scenarios.

Somehow even the most recent books on Einstein's theory like the otherwise brilliant book by Choquet-Bruhat also doesn't dwell on techniques of testing in a collapse scenario whether the curvature singularity is naked or not.

I haven't seen till now any generic method or algorithm for testing this.

It would be great if someone can give me some references/explanations along these lines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question is very broad, and so I'll just give some very broad answers too.

**Collapse scenarios** Are you absolutely sure you want to restrict yourself to dust collapse? In the case of a spherically symmetric scalar field, there is also http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1307898 (and [this paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/121023) which shows that naked singularities in the scalar field model are unstable).

There's some problem of the interpretation of the dust collapse as a physical formation. Here I'll quote Demetri from [his book on vacuum collapse due to incoming gravitational waves](http://arxiv.org/abs/0805.3880)

> With the above remarks in mind the author turned to the study of the
>   gravitational collapse of an inhomogeneous dust ball. In this case, the
>   initial state is still spherically symmetric, but the density is a function of the
>   distance from the center of the ball. The corresponding spherically symmetric
>   solution had already been obtained in closed form by Tolman in 1934, in
>   comoving coordinates, but its causal structure had not been investigated. This
>   required integrating the equations for the radial null geodesics. A very diﬀerent
>   picture from the one found by Oppenheimer and Snyder emerged from this
>   study. The initial density being assumed a decreasing function of the distance
>   from the center, so that the central density is higher than the mean density,
>   it was found that as long as the collapse proceeds from an initial state of low
>   compactness, the central density becomes inﬁnite before a black hole has a
>   chance to form, thus invalidating the neglect of pressure and casting doubt on
>   the predictions of the model from this point on, in particular on the prediction
>   that a black hole eventually forms.

Essentially the same comment was made by Hájíček in his MathReviews on the dust collapse paper.

**Modern re-writes** Part of the reason that there are no modern re-writes of the proof is because of what I mentioned above, that the violation of weak cosmic censorship is unphysical (so it didn't attract that much attention). On the other hand, the basic idea behind the proof is not too hard (it is in the implementation of the analysis that is difficult). Simply speaking, in spherical symmetry, there is a lot of qualitative information that can be extracted without knowing too much details of the matter model involved (we must have matter as for vacuum, spherically symmetric space-times, we have Birkhoff's theorem). Perhaps a best modern reference is [Mihalis Dafermos' paper in CQG](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2145241). The most important part is that under symmetry conditions and some mild assumptions, future null infinity must be complete; in the spherically symmetric space-times, future null infinity is characterised by the area-radius $r\to\infty$ along out-going null geodesics. Thus the basic idea is to show that there exists out-going null geodesics, such that if you travel along the future direction the area radius increases without bound, and that if you travel along the past direction you will hit the singularity.

Now, in the case of the Tolman dust which was studied by Christodoulou, since the exterior of the dust cloud is glued to a Schwarzschild solution, there is a dichotomy: either the out-going null geodesic escapes the dust region before hitting the apparent horizon, or the null geodesic hits the apparent horizon first. In spherical symmetry, it is a general fact that the apparent horizon consists of space-like or expanding null portions. So once a null geodesic passes the apparent horizon it can no longer escape to infinity. On the other hand, inside the Schwarzschild region the apparent horizon agrees with the event horizon, so once the null geodesic escapes from dust without hitting the apparent horizon, it will remain in the domain of outer communications and escape to infinity.

So to demonstrate existence of naked singularity, it suffices to show that a null geodesic emanating from the first point of singularity (it doesn't make sense to consider later points, as they will no longer belong to the Cauchy development of an initial data set) will escape the dust cloud before hitting the apparent horizon. To do so one needs to estimate the size of the solution of an ODE. In spherical symmetry, the apparent horizon is characterised by $2m/r = 1$, where $m$ is the Hawking mass and $r$ is the area radius. Now the Hawking mass satisfies ordinary differential equations (with source) in spherical symmetry (see, for example, Equation 3 [here](http://williewong.wordpress.com/2010/01/28/the-hoop-conjecture-of-kip-thorne-and-spherically-symmetric-space-times/); or see Section 3 of [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF00375144).) So to estimate the size of the Hawking mass at the matching boundary, it is necessary to estimate the source terms in the ODE. This will lead to equation chasing using the Einstein equations and the matter-field equations. The rest is just being clever (in deciding in which order to estimate the various quantities) and doing the hard work of computation.

**General techniques** The reason there are no references for general techniques in testing whether a singularity is naked or not is very simply, *there exists no such techniques*. In spherical symmetry there is the simple description I posted above, but at the end of the day the estimates strongly depend on the structure of the matter equation (its separability and what not), so can only be really dealt with in a case-by-case basis. Of course, *if* you are given an explicit solution of the equations, testing whether the singularity is naked is often a simple computation re-writing the solution in some sort of null coordinates. The problem is that to prove genericity or to study singularities without reference to a explicit solution, one needs analytical estimates which, like I said, depends on which equations you are studying. In fact, if you could come up with a usable, generic method of testing whether a singularity is clothed, you would be half-way there resolving the general weak cosmic censorship conjecture.

**Some last comments** The general issue of weak cosmic censorship is a wide open one. The problem is that the statement contains the word "generic" in it (generic initial data sets lead to blah blah blah). So while there has been quite a lot of work going into constructing solutions and verifying that those solutions contain naked singularities, these works say nothing about weak cosmic censorship. (Explicit solutions tend to be non-generic in the space of solutions, except in the case you have strong rigidity theorems like Birkhoff's theorem for spherically symmetric Einstein-vacuum/electro-vacuum space-times or the No Hair Theorem for four-dimensional stationary axi-symmetric solutions.) The only real progress to weak cosmic censorship have all been due to Christodoulou (most of the physics papers are lacking in rigour). (Interestingly, there has been more developments in strong cosmic censorship, which, despite the name, has relatively little to do with weak cosmic censorship.)

Most recently, the focus in the community seems to be that the next model to consider for cosmic censorship should be the Einstein-Vlasov model (in spherical symmetry). (Well, it has been under consideration for around 10 years now and still prohibitingly hard.) For general solutions without symmetry assumptions, there has been essentially zero work in the field. There was an [attempt](http://stacks.iop.org/0264-9381/16/i=12A/a=302) to reformulate the conjecture into something mathematically tractable, but not has been done with the reformulation.

Comment: @Willie Thanks a lot for this amazingly detailed answer! When you say that "future null infinity is complete" I suppose you mean just what you said in the next line about the spatial scale growing unbounded along null geodesics. Or are you making some statement also about the structure of the future null infinity? Further is this test of yours the same as the "future in/completeness theorem" by Choquet and Costakis? (which relies on the nature of the lapse function for a regularly sliced space-time) ? 

Comment: Contd. The statement of Strong Censorship Conjecture that Choquet quotes is the one formalized by Eardley and Moncrief which states that a maximal globally hyperbolic vacuum Einstein development of generic initial data is inextensible if the initial data is asymptotically euclidean or compactly supported. In this formulation how does the existence of event horizon view point fit in? 



Comment: Contd. Your definition of the apparent horizon sounds a bit new to me. Can you kindly relate it to the definition using the Ricci tensor? Also Christodoulou talks about whether or not the null geodesic from the singularity can or cannot escape before the apparent horizon forms. (assuming equations of state such that there was no apparent horizon to begin with). Can you kindly explain this dynamical view of the apparent horizon which is a bit confusing since it seems that once I am given the metric the apparent horizon is completely known. 

Comment: Completeness of future null infinity means that, under suitable compactification, the null generators of future null infinity are complete (as null geodesics). It is not the same as the statement about spatial scale. The precise definition is given in the last paper I cited in my answer (though you should only consider the future direction, not the past one). Which paper of Choquet and Costakis are you referring to? I cannot find any paper jointly authored by them on MathSciNet. 

Comment: As to strong cosmic censorship, the idea is thus: there can be no extension past future null infinity anyway (it is a cosmological horizon). But in the interior of the black hole region (past the endpoint of the event horizon), there may exist a Cauchy horizon (the Cauchy horizon indicates the boundary of the maximal globally hyperbolic development of some initial data set). In the Schwarzschild solution, this boundary is singular (corresponding to the r = 0 singularity). In the Reissner-Nordstrom solution, this boundary is regular (corresponding to the inner horizon). 

Comment: (Such a horizon also exists for the Kerr family of black holes, so they also form in the vacuum case.) The metric can be analytically extended in those space-times to beyond the domain of dependence of the initial data set. Cosmic censorhip states that this is exceptional: that most spacetimes should have the Cauchy horizon be singular. Now, the "boundary" of the domain of dependence of asymptotically flat initial data comes in two parts. The part that is null infinity, and the part that is Cauchy horizon inside the black hole. 

Comment: Roughly speaking, if you can prove that no event horizon forms, you won't have to worry at all about the existence of Cauchy horizons and hence you don't worry about strong cosmic censorship at all. Lastly, what is your definition using the Ricci tensor? An apparent horizon by definition is a closed achronal orientable two surface such that both future null expansions are negative. It does not depend on the Ricci tensor at all! (Think Schwarzschild, where Ricci = 0 everywhere). In the case of spherical symmetry, each sphere of constant $r$ and constant $t$ is a two surface isometric

Comment: (contd) to the standard sphere. In a "standard" situation, the two future null expansions have different signs. So their product is negative. In a trapped situation, the two future null expansions have the same sign (apparent horizon is give by the outer most trapped surface), so their product is positive. In spherical symmetry, the product of the null expansions is proportional (by a constant positive factor) to $g(\nabla r, \nabla r)$, which turns out to equal $1 - 2m / r$ with $m$ the Hawking mass. Hence the definition. It is actually fairly standard.

Comment: It is true that once you are given the metric, the apparent horizons are known. The problem is that we are studying an evolutionary problem: you are only given the metric on some initial data set. So you have two choices: either solve explicitly for the metric from the Cauchy data and try to find the apparent horizon that way, or use PDE estimates to get a good sense where the apparent horizon ought to form. 

Comment: @Willie Thanks a lot for the extensive discussions. The Choquet-Costakis result that I was mentioning is in their paper in 2002 in J.Geom.Phys.43(4),345-350. Though I picked it up from Choquet's book. About the apparent horizon the definition I was referring to was the one that is used in spherically symmetric cases as $g^{\mu \nu}\nabla _\mu R \nabla _\nu R = 0$ (where $R$ is the Ricci scalar). 

Comment: (Contd.) It would be illuminating to see what is the connection between this and the idea you mentioned. Like from this definition how does one see that the apparent horizon is in some sense the envelope of the trapped surfaces. About naked singularities one sees in literature that a lot of effort has gone into analyzing the shell-focussing and shell-crossing singularities. Where do they fit into the larger picture? 

Comment: (Contd.) This has given rise to ideas of a "singularity curve" (of which I don't know a precise definition) sign of whose derivative at the curvature singularity is supposed to be a test of nakedness of the singularity. You have insights about this? I hear that in some sense the Klainerman-Rodnianski's famous recent work vastly generalizes this Choquet-Costakis result. If you can shed light on what is the essential deep point about the results established by Klainerman and Rodnianksi in the last few years. 

Comment: Ack! (1) I don't think she ever went by Choquet alone. Please do cite Choquet-Bruhat in the future. (2) Spherically symmetric case the R you refer to should be the area radius, NOT the Ricci Scalar (in the formula for apparent horizon). The apparent horizon corresponds to when one of the null expansion is zero. Hence one of the null derivatives of the area radius must be zero. (Null expansion = rate of change of area.) The expression you wrote down $g(\nabla R,\nabla R)$ is by the definition of the Hawking mass $1 - 2M/R$. 

Comment: Don't know about the singularity curve notion. And there's no way I'll have enough space here on MO to even begin to sketch Klainerman and Rodnianski's work. (I assume you meant their work on the $L^2$ curvature conjecture.) If you want to talk more, send me an e-mail. You can find it on my webpage linked from my MO profile. 

Comment: Just took a look at the Choquet-Bruhat--Cotsakis result you mentioned. Their notion of completeness is that of geodesic completeness of the entire space-time. It is a stronger statement then completeness of null infinities. In particular by Penrose singularity theorem, reasonable black hole spacetimes cannot be null geodescically complete. The paper also tackles a vastly different problem then what Klainerman and Rodnianski do. One cannot really compare the results at all. 

Comment: @Willi Thanks for the reply. Apologies I was badly misreading the meaning of the symbol $R$. Vaguely this is what I understand of this analysis using the singularity curve. In a spherically symmetric case it is supposedly the curve in the $t-r$ space along which the spatial scale is $0$.

Comment: (Contd.)  Then the point of view advocated in a series of papers by Joshi-Dwiwedi and Joshi-Goswami is that this singularity curve gives the dependence of the apparent horizon on $r$ and if the apparent horizon becomes a decreasing function of $r$ near the singularity then the singularity gets trapped and its not naked and the converse happens if the function is increasing. So much of their analysis is about determining the parity of the second derivative of the singularity curve at the singularity. 

Comment: (Contd.) So what do you think of this singularity curve argument?  Thanks for pointing out this Cauchy horizon issue. I guess the idea is that weak censorship does not rule out this case and these will be called "locally naked". But there are issues about stabilities of such Cauchi Horizons. I don't know the details but some 1983 results by Chandrashekhar and Hartle showed that this Reissner-Nordstrom Cauchy horizon is "infinite blue-shift unstable" but apparently stable Cauchy horizons have been shown by Morris-Thorne-Yetsever in 1989 in some other example. 

Comment: (Contd.) As far as I understand that both the weak and the strong censorship conjectures demand the complement of the black-hole region to be globally hyperbolic. Anything more they demand of the topology? Choquet-Bruhat in her book says that the Klainerman-Rodnianski's 2008 result is some relaxation of assumptions of their 2002 results.
And thanks for the offer to communicate over emails. Once I have gotten an idea of what the papers you linked to talk of, I will try to send you an email to discuss further. 



Comment: On Choquet-Bruhat/Klainerman-Rodnianski: in so far as assumptions, yes, conditions are relaxed (I now realize that you are comparing the result to the breakdown criterion result). But I think the philosophy and applications for the two results are different. A propos strong cosmic censorship: most of so-called (in)stability results from the physics literature are non rigorous and imprecise. Now, it is "hard" to actually make the Chandrasekhar-Hartle result rigorous, since the only spherically symmetric electrovacuum soltion is Reissner-Nordstrom. 

Comment: One first attempt at exploiting the infinite blue-shift effect is to study the Einstein-Maxwell-Scalar field equation (with only gravitational, and no electromagnetic coupling). This was done by Mihalis Dafermos in his dissertation at Princeton, where he shows strong cosmic censorship in $C^1$, but also violation in $C^0$. In other symmetry classes, a good review of the state of the art is http://arxiv.org/abs/0710.1351 by Smulevici, and the work on Gowdy space-times by Hans Ringstrom. 

Comment: @Willie Thanks for your helpful insights. I will probably send you an email to discuss further. 
