# Naked curvature singularity vs Cauchy horizon in stably causal space-time

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, general-relativity

[There is a result](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00054475)
that says (*theorem 2.11*) that any **stably causal** space-time $M$ is either a product $\Sigma\times \mathbb{R}$ or the time-like gradient $\nabla f$ of a time function $f:M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is an **incomplete** vector field. Let's further suppose that $M$ has **no event horizon** nor closed trapped surface.

I want to know if this time-like incompleteness (in a stably causal) + no event horizon implies a "naked" curvature singularity or could one instead have only (in principle, strong cosmic censorship notwithstanding) a Cauchy horizon **without** the curvature singularity?

Also, I should perhaps attach the word **maximal**? So as to exclude silly counterexamples where you remove a point from Minkowski or something of the sort. I think there is an example by Christodoulou where you have both a naked singularity and a Cauchy horizon but I was wondering if you could have, in principle, examples with just the Cauchy horizon. or must there be a curvature singularity always?

Thanks!

Comment: I found [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37812/christodoulous-paper-on-naked-singularities-in-inhomogeneous-dust-collapse?noredirect=1&lq=1) made by @WillieWong that "Roughly speaking, if you can prove that no event horizon forms, you won't have to worry at all about the existence of Cauchy horizons". Perhaps Willie or someone can point me to a references where they explain this in more detail?  Is this only true for asymptotically flat space-times? I believe the **roughly** excludes Chirstodoulou's solution so is there an extra hypothesis needed like genericity?